# How can I iterate over a list and trim based on window size?

Tags: jquery

I have some funky behavior happening and I'm not sure why (novice here). I am hoping your more trained eyes can see what I'm doing wrong.

**THE GOAL**
As the screen resizes, the longer titles will be trimmed replaced by "..." (haven't added the ... yet).

**WHATS HAPPENING**
For some reason I'm only getting the first title in the list (CEO), and (theString) for the rest of the elements in the list, even though I am using each(). Also, this might be because it's not working correctly yet, the entire div is being trimmed, regardless of the window size.

You can see in the Console that only the first one is being logged, and the trimming is not working correctly.

**LIVE VERSION**
Here's where you can see the actual code at work (the snippet editor may be too small):

https://stable.stable-demos.com/who-we-are/

```js
// TRIM THE WORDS
$('.team-title').each(function() {

  
  var theString = $(this).html(); //the string
  function trimWords(){//change number of words depending on width in the category blog page


  console.log(theString);

  console.log("theString ",theString);
   var contentWidth = $(document).width(); //get width of browser
   if(contentWidth < 600){
    var maxLength = 80 // maximum number of characters to extract
   }
   else if (contentWidth >= 600 && contentWidth < 1025){
    var maxLength = 400   
   }
   else if (contentWidth >= 1025 && contentWidth < 1279){
    var maxLength = 40   
   }
   else if (contentWidth >= 1279){
    var maxLength = 75   
   }
   //trim the string to the maximum length
   var trimmedString = theString.substr(0, maxLength);

   //re-trim if we are in the middle of a word
   console.log(trimmedString, maxLength);
   trimmedString = trimmedString.substr(0, Math.min(trimmedString.length, trimmedString.lastIndexOf(" ")));
   $(".team-title").html(trimmedString);
  }
  trimWords();
  $(window).resize(trimWords)
  
});
```

```css
.teams-wrap li {
 list-style: none;
}

/* Image */
.box {
    position: relative;
}
.box img {
    width: 350px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.active img {
 display: block;
}

/* Name and Title */
.team-details {
 font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.team-details a {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.team-details a:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.team-content,
.flex-this {
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1.4rem;
}
.team-content .box {
 flex: 1;
}
.flex-this .item {
 width: 50%;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
  .mobile-only {
   display: block;
  }
  .teams-wrap li {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   padding: 20px 0;
  }
  .team-title {
   font-size: 1.0rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="teams-wrap">

<ul>

<li class="team-content">

<div class="box team-image">

<img src="https://stable.stable-demos.com/wp-content/uploads/chad-hetherington-2.jpg" alt="">

                        </div>

<div class="box team-details">

<a class="flex-this">
<div class="item team-name">Chad Hetherington</div>  
<div class="item team-title"></div>
</a>   

</div> 

</li>


<li class="team-content">

<div class="box team-image">

<img src="https://stable.stable-demos.com/wp-content/uploads/nik-larsen-2.jpg" alt="">

                        </div>

<div class="box team-details">

<a class="flex-this">
<div class="item team-name">Nik Larsen</div>  
<div class="item team-title"></div>
</a>   

</div> 

</li>


<li class="team-content">

<div class="box team-image">

<img src="https://stable.stable-demos.com/wp-content/uploads/Carly-Broderick-2.png" alt="">

                        </div>

<div class="box team-details">

<a class="flex-this">
<div class="item team-name">Carly Broderick</div>  
<div class="item team-title"></div>
</a>   

</div> 

</li>

</ul>          

</div>
```